# Golang return lower case json key

Tags: json, go

I send Json data with net/http package by an Url, i want to have some lowercase keys in return, but it's not working.

In this example of the problem, i want lowercase 'count' and 'data' key.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type tableau struct {
    Count int      `json"count"`
    Data  []People `json"data"`
}

type People struct {
    Id   int    `json"Id"`
    Name string `json"Name"`
    Age  int    `json"Age"`
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/people", recupPeople)
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("Static"))
    http.Handle("/", fs)
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}

func recupPeople(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    listPeople := &tableau{
        Count: 4,
        Data: []People{
            People{Id: 1, Name: "Laurent", Age: 20},
            People{Id: 2, Name: "Laurent", Age: 20},
        },
    }
    peop, _ := json.Marshal(listPeople)
    fmt.Println(string(peop))
    w.Write(peop)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(listPeople)
}
```

But when i check the URL i didn't have lower case.
[image]

Cordially,
Laurent

Comment: Your tags are malformed: `\`json:"count"\``

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot colon in tag declaration. As tags are not in proper format, field names are in your json.

Try this:

```
type tableau struct {
    Count int      `json:"count"`
    Data  []People `json:"data"`
}
```

Comment: Just one note: since the Json thing wasn't done correctly the encoder was grabbing the field name.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a `:` to your struct tags:

```
type tableau struct {
    Count int      `json:"count"`
    Data  []People `json:"data"`
}
```